# Not able to get date or header from "From" line with MimeKit

Tags: c#, mimekit

When I try to parse an MBOX file with MimeKit, it fails at grabbing the first line which starts with "From". When I try to import the same data in Thunderbird (ImportExportTools NG), it parses the first line.

Here is a sample section that is not working

```
From 1234@test Sat Feb  3 05:50:57 2018
From: Test Name <test.name@test.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain

Hello
```

MimeKit seems to be only recognizing this

```
From: Test Name <test.name@test.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Maybe I am going about it incorrectly, would love some guidance on how to get the date from the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mbox From-lines are not part of a MIME message, they are just markers in an mbox file.

You can get access to the mbox marker (aka From-line) from the MimeParser via the [MboxMarker](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/P_MimeKit_MimeParser_MboxMarker.htm) property.

Comment: Nope, there is no formal standard. The only thing you can count on is that the marker will start with “From “.